# Starting multiple structured streaming apps in Spark standalone Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have Spark Cluster with one master node, three slaves and one master backup master node. Of course zookeeper as node for its self. Running in standalone mode. I want to run multiple Pyspark scripts using Kafka+Spark Structured Streaming+some db. One script is with sink to Cassandra data base, writing raw data, second is aggregating data to MongoDB, third is about some window aggregations etc. I am starting my scripts with spark-submit for each script and when I start first one it runs smoothly, but it occupies all resources(all cores) and second app is gonna be in waiting state, and third as well. I tried putting --executor-cores 3, and since my worker nodes have 4 cores each(sum=12)  it leaves 4  cores for second app and then it runs as it should. So that is some workaround, but I doubt that that's the right way to schedule resource management. Of course I tried with 
`spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "pool1")` for each app other pool name, but I god no improvement. I am new to this Clustering thing and probably I am doing something that is not by the book, and that is why I am asking for someone more experienced for help.

Comment: Why not use Kafka Connect plugins instead? Datastax maintains one for Cassandra . Mongo has one as well

Comment: I have some complicated queries in some scripts.

Comment: Okay. That doesn't exactly answer the question. You can still use Spark to read and write to Kafka topics. Anything to a database can use code by other people